# tramp hanging on remote fish shell despite tramp-remote-shell being /bin/sh

Tags: tramp, remote, fish-shell

I can't connect via Tramp to a remote machine since switching to using fish as my default shell. However I have the tramp-remote-shell set for "/bin/sh" but this seems to be only used for interactive sessions. Annoyingly switch back to bash as my default-shell I still get failures:

```
09:39:17.904971 tramp-process-one-action (5) # Looking for regexp "\(^[^#$%>
]*[#$%>] *\)\'" from remote shell
09:39:17.905142 tramp-process-one-action (5) # Call ‘tramp-action-succeed’
09:39:17.905535 tramp-process-actions (3) # Waiting for prompts from remote shell...done
09:39:17.905931 tramp-maybe-open-connection (3) # Found remote shell prompt on ‘torrent’
09:39:17.907315 tramp-get-remote-stat (5) # Finding a suitable ‘stat’ command
09:45:50.841514 tramp-file-name-handler (1) # Interrupt received in operation (file-attributes /ssh:torrent:/files-x.elc string)
"/bin:/usr/bin"
tramp_exit_status 0
[~] $ 
09:45:50.842029 tramp-file-name-handler (1) # Interrupt received in operation (file-readable-p /ssh:torrent:/files-x.elc)
"/bin:/usr/bin"
tramp_exit_status 0
[~] $ 
09:45:50.842926 tramp-maybe-open-connection (3) # Opening connection for torrent using ssh...failed
```

Despite having a very simple prompt setup. This seems to be infuriatingly random as my tramp setup seems to vary from working to being broken with apparent randomness.

Comment: Hard to say something useful. Best you would produce traces with `tramp-verbose` set to 10, and present them on the Tramp ML, `<tramp-devel@gnu.org>`. Debugging is out of scope on sx.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: My problem was linked to `neotree`. See https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/b9p6oe/tramp_and_ssh_issues/

Comment: Mine was broken by a nil in load-path caused by my setup. Didn't figure out the root cause though.